# comparison of strings - JAVA

Tags: java, string

Ok, I know there is millions of answers to this question "how do I compare strings" but I have made sure I have researched as many as I can to fix my problem but I cannot find an answer...

I am making a network chat server and client in java that runs over udp using `DatagramSockets` (even though stream over tcp would make much more sense). I want to have a way to exit the chat program on either side when the user types `exit`. To get user input I am using a `Scanner` which I have declared in a method called `getMessage` in the class `getter.getMessage`. Here is the code I am working on now:

```
getter.getMessage();
String pTest = getter.smessage;
if(pTest.equals("exit")) {
  System.out.println("System going offline");
  getter.isOn = false;
}
```

This gets ignored everytime around my while loop, even when the user input is exit. I also tried:

```
if(getter.message.toLowerCase().Equals("exit") {
  //blah
}
```

I had originally tried by not putting getter.message into the `String pTest` but it just doesn't want to work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to debug this. Print out getter.smessage before and after calling getMessage() to see if it really works. Maybe there is trailing withspace you want to trim?

Comment: maybe smessage contains a newline? in which case `"exit\n".equals("exit")` would return false

Comment: Also, it's best to do `"exit".equals(pTest)` to avoid null pointer exceptions.

Comment: ahjhhhhhthe printing a new line seems like a highly likely possibility, let me see... as in scanner I am using nextLine()

Comment: How about using equalsIgnoreCase?

Comment: Have you tried printing out what pTest is ? Also print out its length to make sure you didn't take in a space or something

Comment: Newline, or space, or binary junk, depending on how you're doing the network communication. Remember that `\0` doesn't terminate a Java string the way it terminates a C string; if you turn a `byte` array into a `String`, you might end up with a bunch of extra bytes on the end if you're not careful.

Comment: ok so before pTest.trim(); it says 11 and after it says 10. So the issue is white space right?

Comment: I feel like this is the best option: If anybody has time to take a look    http://pastebin.com/HX8Ambrm

Comment: If you are receiving 10 or 11 bytes for `"exit"`, there's almost certainly an encoding problem. See my revised answer for how to deal with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ("exit".equalsIgnoreCase(getter.message.trim())) {
    . . .
}
```

**EDIT**

You mentioned in a comment that when you are expecting `"exit"` you are receiving 11 characters (10 after calling `trim()`). This suggests that there's an encoding mismatch with the data. Perhaps the server is sending UTF-16 data with a byte order mark at the beginning. (This would explain the byte count.) If you are then reading it using the platform-default encoding (usually ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8), you are converting each byte into a character and it will never match `"exit"`. You need to get both sides of the encoding to match.

Once you know the encoding used to send the data, create your `Scanner` using a constructor that takes a character encoding. For instance, it might be:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-16");
```

Comment: +1. I prefer this over the other way around for the look. I don't really know why else.

Comment: Ok as far As I am aware both sides should be using the same encoding as they are running on the same machine and it is not declared anywhere to use any other coding, ill pastebin the client side

Comment: ok so i only call indiviual methods so could i call getter.getMessage(inputStream", utf-16");?

Comment: @Charlie - You are definitely using the default encoding to read `System.in`. I don't see anything that confirms that this is the problem, but I strongly suspect it. Try reading the raw bytes into a byte array and examining them with a debugger (or printing them in hex). There are encodings other than UTF-16 (e.g., base-64) that will double the byte count.

Comment: ok well, ill look into it, this whole project is for a demo tomorrow and i have already taken it way past what they wanted so I will leave it till the morning and talk to one of my lecturers about it. Thanks for all your help :-)

Comment: @Jon - I like putting the constant first because I don't have to read through the entire expression and untangle the parenthesis nesting to figure out the role of the constant. It's right up front that I'm comparing it to some string expression.

Answer (score 0):

It might be problem of white/blank spaces. try following code,

```
if (getter.message.toLowerCase().trim().Equals("exit") )
{
   //blah
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming getter.message is returning something. Have you tried checking the "length" of the String returned from getter.message?

I have never tried anything like this, but faced a similar problem in AJAX. The length of the String returned from the server was greater than the String I was comparing. And I had to remove the unwanted spaces before comparison.

Comment: the size is saying 10 when i use trim() even though pTest should just be exit.